# Obtaining the matched dataset from the Matching package in R by Sekhon

Tags: r, standards, effects, confidence-interval

I have used the matching package by Sekhon and my issue is getting the matched data set. The documentation does not explain how to do it for propensity score matching it only explains for genMatch which I am not using.

Comment: Hi zaiko, when I start working with a new package like `matching` I read the paper that describes the problem area and how it is solved. There is a lot of good information [here](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v042i07) that includes the paper, example code from the paper. I find this approach is easier than starting with the help files. what does your data look like? `dput(head(your_data, n = 10))` to share here by editing your post above.

Comment: Thanks Chris. From the Package "matching"  it  does not seem show how to output the matched data set using propensity scores. Maybe you can show me how to do it with the lalonde dataset used in the paper that you attached.

Comment: so, making sure we have same starting point, `library(Matching)` then `data(lalonde)` we examine what is in `?lalonde`. in Details: we see that there are two demos, `DehejiaWahba` and `AbadieImbens`. we run a demo with `demo('DehejiaWahba', package = 'Matching', ask = TRUE)`. We are asked for user input in the form of hitting return, and a fully worked example is executed. Scrolling up we can see all the steps used. Two demos of propensity score. Three including `?GerberGreenImai`.

Comment: Thank you Chris!

Answer (score 0):

If you have done matching without replacement (i.e., `replace = FALSE`) and with no ties (i.e., `ties = FALSE`), this is straightforward. If `dat` is your dataset and `M` is the output of a call to `Match()`, you can run

```
matched <- dat[c(M$index.treated, M$index.control),]
```

and the matched dataset will be stored in the object `matched`. You can recover pair membership by running

```
matched$pair <- factor(rep(M$index.treated, 2))
```

When matching with replacement or with ties, it becomes more complicated because some units are matched to more than one unit in the other group. You can use the same code to extract the matched units, but units will appear multiple times and therefore need to be weighted. The weights exist in `M$weights`, and there is one for each pair, so the weights need to be repeated (i.e., `weights <- rep(M$weights, 2)`) to get a weight for each unit in the new dataset.

If you just want to get matching weights for a matched dataset, regardless of how the matching was done, discarding pair membership, you can use the `get.w()` function in the `cobalt` package, which extracts weights, one for each unit in the original dataset, as follows:

```
 weights <- get.w(M)
```

`length(weights)` should equal `nrow(dat)`.

Comment: Thanks Noah this is quite useful